# Почему 2д персонаж очень медленно падает и не прыгает?

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;
 
public class PlayeMoving : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Vector2 direction;
    public Transform transform;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public PlayerControls playerControls;
    public bool isGrounded = false;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    public float jumpForce = 5f;
 
    private void Awake()
    {
        playerControls = new PlayerControls();
    }
 
    public void DirectOn(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        direction = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }
 
    public void Jump(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * speed, direction.y * speed);
    }
 
    void Update()
    {
        //transform.Translate(direction * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        //rb.MovePosition((Vector2)transform.position + (direction * speed ));
    }
 
    private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
        {
            isGrounded = false;
        }
    }
 
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D coll)
    {
        if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Platform"))
        {
            isGrounded = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код, персонаж совсем не прыгает и очень медленно падает.

Comment: @aepot О, получилось

Comment: решение больше не нужно( ты пишешь: "О, получилось")?

Comment: @Кирилл Не, решение ещё нужно. Я имел ввиду что код получилось сюда залить

Comment: проверь настройки гравитации в Project Settings  и массу Player

Comment: @Кирилл Там всё нормально, если отключить движение персонажа (rb.velocity = new Vector2(direction.x * speed, direction.y * speed);) то он нормально падать будет